# Jmeter Distribution Configuration setup

Tags: jmeter

done the following steps:
 Master machine > edit jmeter file and put the remote host ip =10.21.4.199 and slave machine start jmeter-server.All machine are same subnet & same version of java and jmeter.
Problem are : 1> Not running slave machine.Can provide steps by steps, Plz dont add common pdf of jmeter distribution pdf.
2>Script running without having remote host, put blank.
3>Its compulsory to run script on master machine?

Could you explain some other point meaning :

```
# RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port)
server_port=443 
#server.rmi.port=1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps from **windows machine**:

1. Start **only jmeter-server.bat** from the slave machines. (no need to run both jmeter.bat and jmeter-server.bat)
2. Configure **jmeter.properties** file of the master machine as follows:

> Remote Hosts - comma delimited
>
> remote_hosts=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1,xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 (IP of your slave machines)

3. Start **jmeter.bat** from client (master) machine.
4. Now you can run your test from GUI mode to check everything is okay or not.

To do this: **Run->Remote start-> check the IP's of slaves. (if its in there you are ready to run your test remotely).**

**Pre-requisites:**

1. All the machines (both master and slaves) must be in the **same subnet**.
2. **Firewall** must be turned off for all machines.
3. **Java and JMeter versions** must be same for all machines.

**Problem 1:**

I'm pretty much afraid on that you have missed the 2nd point above. So please check the **Firewall section**. It may be the cause of not running the slave machines.

**Problem 2:**

Your second problem is not clear to me. What problems are you facing here? Please mention precisely.

**Problem 3:**

For Distributed testing, **it is obvious** to run a script on the master machine.

RMI Registry acts a broker between RMI servers and the clients. See [Introduction to Java RMI](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html). Excerpt:

> Figure 1 shows the connections made by the client when using RMI. Firstly, the client must contact an RMI registry, and request the name of the service. Developer B won't know the exact location of the RMI service, but he knows enough to contact Developer A's registry. This will point him in the direction of the service he wants to call.

And this is done to launch your **Slave** machine to communicate with the **Client machine**.It will dynamically assign a listening port to listen from Client. In your case, `port 443` is configured manually from the `jmeter.properties` file.

Comment: As per my understanding master machine just monitor the slave activity not thread running in master in case run remote all. 3> what use of server port & # On the client:
# - set remote_hosts=server:1234  (its slave ip with port ????), # On the server(s) # - set server_port=1234 (its also slave port or application port ????) # - start rmiregistry with port 1234 (????),  #server.rmi.localport=4000 (????)

Comment: From the [Apache Jmeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), One instance of the JMeter client can control any number of remote JMeter instances, and collect all the data from them. JMeter server application starts the RMI registry itself; there is no need to start RMI registry separately. JMeter/RMI requires a connection from the client to the server. This will use the port you chose, default 1099.

Comment: Yes, you should configure on the client(master) machine's properties file as remote_hosts=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1,xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 (IP of your slave machines)

Comment: By default, RMI uses a dynamic port for the JMeter server engine. This can cause problems for firewalls, so with you can define the JMeter property server.rmi.localport to control this port number.

I recommend you to read the Documentation properly. Thanks